# Error - Space Manager Invalid

Tags: catalina, disk-utility, apfs, fsck

My computer was stuck in a boot loop so I connected the drive to another computer and ran fsck. i get the error "failed to read spaceman cib 0xfcfe" "Space manager is invalid" "The volume /dev/disk3s1 could not be verified completely". Is there any way to get the data off this drive? (APFS)

Comment: Failed to mount Joy Jin

Comment: "Volume on disk failed to mount. Perhaps the operation is not supported (kDAReturnUnsupported). If it has a partitioning scheme, use diskutil mountDisk". If you think the volume is supported but damaged try the readOnly option.

Comment: Is the OS the volume seems to be mounted and i can open it but my user account is missing along with many other files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116800/discussion-between-junaid-and-joy-jin).